# Rotation in local frame, expressed as quaternion

Tags: rotation, quaternions, coordinate-transformation

The following image shows two coordinate systems A and B, positioned in the global frame G:
[image: coordinate systems configuration]

I need to find quaternion which rotates A to B, but expressed in the frame local to A.

The first part is easy, `B.conjugate()*A` (subtracting the rotation of `B` from the rotation of `A`), which gives π/2 rotation around `(-1,0,0)`. That is obviously correct, since rotating `A` around the global `-x` axis by 90° gives `B`.

Now I need to express that result in the `A`; the desired result is π/2 around `(0,0,-1)` (that's what global `-x` is in A), but I am not able to get there just with rotation composition.

I can convert the quaternion to angle-axis representation (π/2 around `(-1,0,0)`), rotate the axis as `A*(-1,0,0)=(0,0,-1)`, and convert back to quaternion, but I would like to avoid that conversion if possible.

How to get the rotation using quaternion multiplication only?

---

The code itself is c++, but I check that in python with [minieigen](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/minieigen):

```
from minieigen import *
from math import *
A=Quaternion((0,-1,0),pi/2)
B=Quaternion((sqrt(3)/3,-sqrt(3)/3,sqrt(3)/3),(2/3.)*pi)
# rotation in global frame:
rg=B.conjugate()*A           # is Quaternion((-1,0,0),pi/2)
# rotation in local frame:
# ?? what now?! hack around with angle-axis
aa=rg.toAngleAxis()
rl=Quaternion(A*aa[1],aa[0]) # is Quaternion((0,0,-1),pi/2)

for q in A,B,rg,rl: print q
```

which gives:

```
Quaternion((0,-1,0),1.5707963267948966)
Quaternion((0.5773502691896257,-0.5773502691896257,0.5773502691896257),2.0943951023931953)
Quaternion((-1,-7.850462293418876e-17,-7.850462293418876e-17),1.5707963267948968)
Quaternion((-1.1102230246251568e-16,-7.850462293418877e-17,-1),1.5707963267948968)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was an easy one, but I leave it here for the record:

```
A*B.conjugate()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your equations don't quite sit right with me.

I'll use **Q'** for Q.conjugate.  Now we know that **Q'*Q** is the identity and so it **Q*Q'**.  Therefore, if you want to know the quaternion that transforms **A** into **B** (in the global frame since **A** and **B** are both in the global frame), then you start with that equation (assuming that these quaternions represent rotations applied to column vectors):

**Q*A=B**

then you move A over to the other side

**Q*A*A'=B*A'=Q**

This, we can see is correct, because **B*A'*A=B**.  The equation in your questions says, that **B'*A*A=B**.  This doesn't hold true in general, I think.

Now, if you want the rotation to be in **A**'s frame instead of the global frame, that's equivalent to saying that you want **B**, in **A**'s frame.  That's the same as removing **A** from **B**.  Like so: **A'*B**.  This way, if you rotate from **A**'s frame to the global frame, you end up with **B** again: **A*A'*B=B**.